# How to execute sudo commands after login?

Tags: greeter, startup, script

I would like to execute a command which requires sudo privileges. Specifically, I want to set my CPU frequency to a performance governor using the following script.

```
sudo cpufreq-set -g performance
```

What I have done so far is I have added this custom command from `System Settings -> Applications -> Startup`. I also changed the permission of the newly created file from `~/.config/autostart`. However, the sudo command is still not executing. Are there any other ways to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a laptop, you can use TLP to automatically set it.

If you prefer a more simple method, you can create a systemd service that will execute at startup.

`sudo io.elementary.code /etc/systemd/system/cpuperformance.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Set CPU performance governor

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/cpufreq-set -g performance

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Close that file and then execute `sudo systemctl daemon-reload && sudo systemctl enable cpuperformance.service`.

If you want to disable this in the future you can use `sudo systemctl disable cpuperformance.service` and `sudo rm /etc/systemd/system/cpuperformance.service` to remove the file.

Comment: So laptop power management tools are not installed by default in elementary OS? Is TLP the only way to do this kind of high-performance configuration? I looked into Debian and it seems that TLP is also not included by default in their laptop-related packages installed via `tasksel laptop` command.

Comment: No, TLP is not installed by default. And the method I described works on laptops as well however I prefer to use TLP since it allows for many more configurations that you'll probably want to change anyway if you're getting into this sort of thing.

Comment: The thing is, I don't really like installing packages which could have the possibility of conflicting. I already have cpufrequtils installed and actually, it is Debian's recommended way of configuring the CPU governor to use. If I just want to maximize the CPU frequency regardless whether I am on battery or AC power, do I really need to have the tlp package included?

Comment: As I said, you don't need to install tlp. Using a systemd service will work just fine.